# JS Pagination Two Page View

Tags: javascript, pagination

Im having a problem to solve a simple two page view pagination in js.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample Two Page View Navigation</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var maxPage = 15;
    $(function() {
        var output = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < (maxPage / 2); i++) {
            output += '<option>Page '+(i+1)+' and '+(i+2)+'</option>';
        }
        $('.page-view').append(output);
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select class="page-view">
    <option value="0">Select Page</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

The target result that I want is this:

```
<option>Page 1 and 2</option>
<option>Page 3 and 4</option>
<option>Page 5 and 6</option>
```

Not like this:

```
<option>Page 1 and 2</option>
<option>Page 2 and 3</option>
<option>Page 3 and 4</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
  var cnt = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < (maxPage  / 2); i++) {
        output += '<option>Page '+(++cnt)+' and '+(++cnt)+'</option>';
  }
```